# FTP Backup Site minus one directory

Tags: backup, ftp, sftp

I am backing up a site including a huge cache folder use SFTP (FileZilla).I do not really need to backup the wp-cache directory, but do not want to get rid off it either atm. 
Is there a way to use (S)FTP or SCP to backup / copy a site with all files and folders minus one folder and its content? I can really live without a backup of the cache folder and it would save me a lot of time if I could backup the site without that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [filename filter](http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Filename_Filters) in FileZilla.

Other FTP/SFTP clients may have similar functionality.